# File name include "#", when used Documents.Open() to open it, "we couldn't find your file. Was it moved, renamed, or deleted? (C:\aaa\AzureTest_)"

Tags: cpu-word

if "fn" is relative path，"\aaa\AzureTest_#202100001.docx", it will be a error-- "we couldn't find your file. Was it moved, renamed, or deleted?  (C:\aaa\AzureTest_)"

if "fn" is absolute path，such as "c:\aaa\AzureTest_#202100001.docx", it's ok.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestOpenClass tc = new TestOpenClass();
            string fn = @"\aaa\AzureTest_#202100001.docx";
            tc.OpenDocument(fn);
        }
    }

    class TestOpenClass
    {
        object missing = Type.Missing;
        _Application appObject = new Application();
        Document docObject = null;
        public void OpenDocument(string targetFileName)
        {
            try
            {
                
                object location = targetFileName;
                 docObject = appObject.Documents.Open(ref location, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing);
            }
            catch (COMException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What programming language are you using? [edit] your question and add it to tags.